# setting default language in drupal multilingual module

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

In my website, I have 2 language English and Marathi.
1st default language is English and I have added some content too.
but now my requirement is to set default language as Marathi.

I have gone to admin/config/regional/language setting and done default language as Marathi but not its working.

Please someone help to solve this prob.
I want default language on my site as Marathi.

Answer (score 0):

Please check these steps as described on this link, [How to Change the Default Language of a Drupal Site](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/change-language/). You might come to know which step you are missing.

Comment: I have updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem.
In detection and selection, I have change the order i.e I have put default language on 2nd position and problem solved

Comment: How did you come to know to change the order, Just by try and error?

Comment: Is it a reply of @CodeNext's answer?